# How to setup primary keys when there are no unique columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How do I setup a primary key on an existing table when almost all the columns have redundant data?

Comment: Add a new `Id INT IDENTITY()` to the table, maybe, and make it the primary key?

Comment: But this won’t solve the uniquess of the data right ? @marc_s

Comment: It will "solve" that because the value of the identity will be different for each row.

Comment: Note that primary key can be made up of multiple columns if their combined values are unique.

Comment: Yes I wanted to know this information @Alex.

Comment: Got your point @sean Lange

Answer (score 1):

```
 ALTER Table, Add [Table].[Id] column as Identity seed 1 increment 1, save.

 Right click [Id] column, set as primary key, save. Done.
```

> SQL server will added the incrementing values automatically

T-SQL:

```
-- add new "Id" column, make it IDENTITY (= auto-incrementing)
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
GO

-- add new primary key constraint on new column   
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
GO
```

Comment: The sql you posted is great. Why bother with showing the hack of using the GUI? Learning the syntax of the commands is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange still few people are interested to use GUI :)

Comment: Join the club and help steer them away from it. :D